# How to delete files from Teams channels with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: python, scope, microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing a python script which is supposed to download then delete files from Teams group. I've found all the ID I need but my script still doesn't work and I think because of my scope. I'm not sure which one I needed that's why I am here asking.

It stopped working here :

```
client_id = "xxx"
client_secret = "xxx"
tenant_id = "xxx"
scope = "Files.ReadWrite"

token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
data = f"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&scope={scope}"
response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=data)
access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace, intended behavior, and what you've tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the Microsoft Graph API, your scope should be as follows:

```
scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow